# VSCode XDEBUG fantom file open

Tags: битрикс, visual-studio-code, битрикс24, xdebug

Всем привет! Кто пользуется xdebug и VScode (хотя может эта проблема быть понятна и тем кто пользуется PHPStorm) - почему вылетают какие то "левые" файлы, причем как с текущего сервера на котором я работаю с файлом в котором выставил эндпоинты, так и с других серверов на которых у меня настроен xdebug https://youtu.be/63K98NJYmKE

UPD:
Пока мне подсказали что на разных серверах можно использовать разные порты, и на машине с VScod слушать на разных портах разные сервера. Это решит проблему что не будет "прилетов" левых файлов с других серверов. Но не решит проблему того что на текущем сервере, на котором я в данный момент веду отладку файла, у меня все равно будут вылетать файлы которые запускаются ядром CMS (Битрикс).

Как же решить данный вопрос, должен он быть, т.к так работать просто не возможно!

Issue https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/953

Comment: если в настройках стоит "Break at first line", то будут "прилеты", поскольку на странице сайта могут быть ajax запросы к бэку. Надо убрать этот параметр, чтобы дебагер останавливался только на точках останова. Не знаю, где это в вскоде выставить, а в шторме `PHP/Debug`